# Not sure what index to apply to my SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a normalized database structure, which I will try to explain.

3 tables:

- profiles
- keywords
- keyword_profile

Every profile on my website can have a various number of keywords linked to it. Every keyword gets an ID-number in the keywords-table. Every profile gets an ID-number in the profiles table. The keyword_profile table has about 600k rows with a keywordID linked to a profileID.

I have a PRIMARY index on my ID column in the profiles table. 
I have a PRIMARY index on my ID column in the keywords table.
I have a UNIQUE index on my keyword-name column in the keywords table.
I have a PRIMARY index on the keyword_profile table like this: (profile_id, keyword_id)
I have a index on the profile_ID column in the keyword_profile table

Next: when I execute the following query (the specific keyword is named 'dienst'):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT profiles.hoofdrubriek, profiles.plaats, profiles.bedrijfsnaam, profiles.gemeente, profiles.bedrijfsslogan, profiles.straatnaam, profiles.huisnummer, profiles.postcode, profiles.telefoonnummer, profiles.fax,profiles.email, profiles.website, profiles.bedrijfslogo
FROM profiles
INNER JOIN profile_dienst ON profiles.ID = profile_dienst.profile_id
INNER JOIN diensten ON profile_dienst.dienst_id = diensten.ID
WHERE (
diensten.dienst = 'Aannemersdiensten'
)
ORDER BY profiles.grade DESC , profiles.bedrijfsnaam
```

I get the following result. It scans all 600k rows!! That's not really the result I was hoping for.. What indexes can I apply so it won't scan the entire table?

```
id - select_type - table - type - key - rows - Extra
1 - SIMPLE - diensten - const - dienst - 1 - Using temporary; Using filesort
1 - SIMPLE - profile_dienst - index - PRIMARY - 662000 - Using where; Using index
1 - SIMPLE - profiles - eq_ref - PRIMARY - 1 - Using where
```

Thanks for the help guys!!

EDIT: Added SHOW CREATE TABLE results:

```
CREATE TABLE `diensten` (
 `ID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `dienst` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `dienst` (`dienst`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1903 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `profile_dienst` (
 `profile_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `dienst_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`dienst_id`,`profile_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
 `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
...more columns...,
     `grade` int(5) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
     KEY `IDX_TIMESTAMP` (`timestamp`),
     KEY `IDX_NIEUW` (`nieuw`),
     KEY `IDX_HOOFDRUBRIEK` (`hoofdrubriek`),
     KEY `bedrijfsnaam` (`bedrijfsnaam`),
     KEY `grade` (`grade`),
     KEY `gemeente` (`gemeente`),
     KEY `plaats` (`plaats`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on `(profile_id, dienst_id)` and on `(dienst_id, profile_id)` in the association table?

Comment: And an index on `(dienst)` in the `diensten` table?

Comment: I think there is a bit of confusion between the english names and the Dutch names. I guess you can replace keyword with diensten.

Comment: @mucio : that is correct, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for all 3 tables. Otherwise we are all just trying to guess engine, indexes, datatypes.

Comment: @user2704687 well i fully understand Dutch.. can you show the data within diensten.. most likly you need to use divide and conquer  (verdeel en heers (Dutch)) .. to get you data on an better way... looks like the MySQL optimizer is planning to access your tables in the wrong order..  it would be helpfull if you place output of  "show create table" statements here.

Comment: @ypercube, SHOW CREATE added! thanks for the help!

Comment: @Raymond Nijland, SHOW CREATE added! thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2704687 you need to do normalization better.. you are JOINING an varrhar(20) with an mediumint  profile_dienst.dienst_id = diensten.ID thats why an FULL INDEX SCAN is needed.. that is what Explain columns type:index and Extra: "using index" means.. MySQL only can use indexes if the datatypes are the same

Comment: @user2704687  little demo with an inner self join http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ef09/4  when MySQL can use indexes..  INT, SMALLINT, CHAR and VARCHAR datatypes used..  here you can see that JOIN ON and INT and SMALLINT can use indexes and an JOIN on CHAR and VARCHAR also.. but mixing INT with CHAR MySQL can't use indexes and an FULL table scan is needed look at TYPE: ALL

Comment: First, add an index on diensten that contains dienst and dienst_id in that specific order. Second, add an index for columns you are sorting by. Third, reverse order of the joins (start from diensten table) Fourth, fix column types in the join table

Comment: @RaymondNijland, that was it!! Thanks! Too bad I can't check your anwer..

Comment: @user2704687 indeed because your can't check comments i've made an answer from them

Comment: @Sami Korhonen  you should really analyse how mysql uses indexes  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine, it's scanning thought all the values of `profile_dienst` because MySql has to look for the `diensten.ID`. The good news is that is using and index.

You can check for more info about the Extra column of the MySql explain plan here: [EXPLAIN Extra Information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information)

Comment: I can't say I agree. Even though it's using an index, I also have a keyword type with a association table of 24mln+ rows. Even with an index, that runs too slow.

Comment: what is too slow? are the indexed columns numeric types?

Comment: Too slow means that the page takes about 10+ seconds to load. The columns with only number-id's are all mediumint(9). Profile ID's have both numbers and letters and are varchar(20)

Comment: Then my first attempt would be to add in Profile a numeric column with a surrogate ID only numeric, then replace profile_id with this new column also in profile_dienst, build a new index and try to see if this improves performances (I expect so)

Comment: @mucio 1 - SIMPLE - profile_dienst - index - PRIMARY - 662000 - Using where; Using index    this is an FULL INDEX SCAN and MySQL is using an extra checking to see if records are matching, thats is what "Using where" means..

Answer (score 0):

you need to do normalization better.. you are JOINING an varrhar(20) with an mediumint profile_dienst.dienst_id = diensten.ID thats why an FULL INDEX SCAN is needed.. that is what Explain columns type:index and Extra: "using index" means.. MySQL only can use indexes if the datatypes are the same

little demo with an inner self join http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ef09/4 when MySQL can use indexes.. INT, SMALLINT, CHAR and VARCHAR datatypes used.. here you can see that JOIN ON and INT and SMALLINT can use indexes and an JOIN on CHAR and VARCHAR also.. but mixing INT with CHAR MySQL can't use indexes and an FULL table scan is needed look at TYPE: ALL